# Is there something like self for class methods?

Tags: objective-c, metaprogramming

I'm attempting to write an ActiveRecord-esque bit of code in Obj-C, and encountered the following situation: I'm trying to create a static class variable in a base class that gets the inheriting class's name and converts into the table name with pluralization and some other formatting operations. I know that for an instance of a class that one can do something along the lines of the following:

```
tableName = [[[self class] description] stringToTableName];
```

However, this requires one to use `self`. Is it possible to do something along following lines?

```
tableName = [[[inheriting_class class] description] stringToTableName];
```

I'd just prefer to not recalculate the table name for each instance of inherited class objects. I'd also prefer to have this bit of code autogenerate the table name with ruby-style metaprogramming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `[self class]`! When you call a class method in Objective-C, `self` will indicate which class is calling. For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface A: NSObject
+ (void)foo;
@end

@implementation A
+ (void)foo {
  printf("%s called!", [[[self class] description] UTF8String]);
}
@end

@interface B: A @end
@implementation B @end

int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [A foo];
    [B foo];
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

should print

```
A called!
B called!
```

Comment: +1, although you can just do `self` instead of `[self class]`.  In a class method, `self` *is* the `Class`.

Comment: @Dave, true; I've always preferred writing `[self class]` to make it clear that I'm looking for a class.

Comment: In this scenario, how would you declare a variable in the foo method that could be either an A or B depending on which class calls it? something like: typeof(self) record = [[[self class] alloc] init];? Or is id a satisfactory way of doing it?

Comment: @iand675, `id` is perfectly fine. The only reason you'd want to declare it as a specific type is for compile-time checking; but the type is determined at runtime, so there'd be no need for it anyways!

Comment: @iand675 Note the latest version of Clang in Xcode 5 now supports the instancetype keyword. It works just like id but provides type checking. See more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id

Comment: I don't believe you can use property syntax on `self` within a class method.  At least it doesn't work for me.  For example within a class method on NSManagedObject, you couldn't use `self.entity` ... but maybe `[self entity]`

Answer (score 0):

How about using NSStringFromClass() (and NSStringFromSelector() if desired)?

```
NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```