# What to use instead of "id" in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have watched some WWDC videos and noticed that they use something else instead of (id) return type of unknown object.

But I have unfortunately forgot the keyword.
Could anyone tell me why use the new thing instead of 'id' when returning some object?  Especially in init and class methods?

Comment: It is instancetype. Check this question for discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id

Comment: @vikingosegundo How come that comment is not mine? :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Just in that second I thought, I want to spent one day without sarcasm, and just shut the f… up, when sarcastic comments are appropriate.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Still, you can, for example, tell our all-caps username friend SAMIR RATHOD not to downvote my answer just because he is making wrong assumptions.

Comment: @ALLALLCAPSFRIENDS: an good answer is not defined by it length, but by it's correctness.

Comment: Ahh, screw my resolution: If you watch that video again, I am sure the lecturer will be kind enough to repeat that information for you!

Comment: @vikingosegundo could work, but I forgot in what videos, and watching like 30 for this seems overkill

Comment: For sure it is not in the video "HTML, CSS, and DOM for Book Authors" and also not in the Keynote. but hey: what about ["Modern Objective-c"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405)?

Comment: but actually it is in ["404: Advances in Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) — found by searching the PDFs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you by any chance looking for [`instancetype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id)?

Comment: Perhaps you could add the "why use it" part of the question? :)

Comment: @borrrden May I include [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id)?

Comment: Excellent!  Unfortunately that makes this question a duplicate...

Comment: @borrrden (and my answer a "link-only" one, which I don't like :P )

Comment: In response to your mod flag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks. I know that. If you look closely (at the edit history of my answer), you can see that it didn't contain the link originally. The answer was/is literally the one keyword "instancetype".

Comment: I really don't think this rule applies here @RobertHarvey .  My case is that if you took away the link, it would stlil answer the question.  In fact the question was originally just a keyword.  Is taking away the link and just having the keyword better in this case??  The link is purely supplemental info that isn't essential to answer the question, just a nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

`(id)` tells the compiler to expect any kind of object. This makes sense for a method where you honestly have no idea what will come back, for example `NSArray`'s `-(id)objectAtIndex:`. However, in an `init` method you *know* what will be returned: an instance of the object's class or a subclass thereof. For example, `[[NSArray alloc] init]` will never return a `UIButton`.

By providing `instancetype` instead of `id` you tell the compiler what kind of object to expect. This means the compiler can help you prevent errors.

See this link: http://nshipster.com/instancetype/. It will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: It would be good to provide a summary in your answer as well.