# Xcode 5.1 changes -(id) to -(instancetype) when using built-in init snippet. Why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

How come Apple changed the built-in `init` method snippet from:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

to:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what `instancetype` is or are you asking why the snippet was changed?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist actually both. There must be a reason why Apple wants developers to use intancetype instead.

Comment: take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id) for a decent explanation

Comment: Where did you see that snippet? Because I believe `instancetype` is intended for class constructor methods.

Comment: @Merlevede updated my question. Just start type init and then select "init - Objective-C -init Method"

Comment: I avoid the issue by never using snippets.  They take too much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instancetype` is the best return type for Objective-C init methods. If you write `id` instead of `instancetype` in an init method then the compiler will assume you really meant `instancetype` (at least in ARC mode).