# UIButton as UIButton in swift?

Tags: swift

I am watching this Swift tutorial and there is this line:

```
var button:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

two questions:

1. why is that line ending with `as UIButton`? Isn't the line clear enough that the user wants to create a button of system type? It appears to be redundant.
2. is it necessary to declare the type UIButton on the first part of the line? Or in other words, isn't enough to declare it like

> var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System)

I mean, if the part after the equal sign is initializing a button of system type is not that enough for the compiler to infer `button` is a `UIButton`? I mean, Apple said the compiler is smart to infer types.

Comment: Many of **your** questions are *curious* fundamental questions which I also wanted to ask (but I guess you're 2 years ahead of me in the learning curve).Normally you won't find answers to such questions unless asked on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to keep the `as UIButton` downcast. `buttonWithType()` return `AnyObject!`, not `UIButton`, so the downcast is necessary. Other than that, you don't need to explicitly type the variable with `: UIButton`. Since the return type of `buttonWithType()` as downcast to UIButton, the variables type will be inferred to be `UIButton`. This is what you should use:

```
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

Comment: And the underlying reason seems to be that the Objective-C method `buttonWithType:` is declared as returning `id` instead of `instancetype`.

Comment: perfect anser and perfect comment from Martin! Now I see, AnyObject! = id! Thanks!!!

Comment: As of Swift 1.2 you need to use `as!` to force a downcast

Answer (score 7):

Some additional background in addition to the already given answers:
The Objective-C method

```
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
```

returns `id`. This was the "traditional" way to declare a "factory method" in a way that it
can be used from subclasses as well. There is no type cast necessary in

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
```

because `id` can be converted to any Objective-C pointer.

Now the equivalent type to `id` in Swift is `AnyObject`, and the above method is mapped to

```
class func buttonWithType(buttonType: UIButtonType) -> AnyObject!
```

Swift is much more strict and does *not* implicitly convert types, therefore the return value has to be cast to `UIButton` explicitly:

```
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

---

The "modern" approach to declare factory methods is `instancetype` (see for example http://nshipster.com/instancetype/ or [Would it be beneficial to begin using instancetype instead of id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id)). A simple example is
the `NSString` method

```
+ (instancetype)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

which is mapped in Swift to

```
class func stringWithCString(cString: CString, encoding enc: UInt) -> Self!
```

`Self` is the type of the object on which the method is called, so that
the return type of

```
NSString.stringWithCString("foo", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

is `NSString!` and the return type of

```
NSMutableString.stringWithCString("bar", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

is `NSMutableString!`. *No type cast is necessary* in Swift. In the following
example, the Swift compiler "knows" that `str` is an `NSString`:

```
var str = NSString.stringWithCString("foo", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var cs = str.UTF8String
```

The Foundation framework headers already use `instancetype` in many places, but not
yet everywhere where possible (as in `buttonWithType:`). This may be improved in
future releases of the SDKs.

Comment: how is that buttons are *class* methods? Or is that an **instance** of a UIButton is equal to one of the factory methods/class methods of the UIButton?

Comment: @Honey:  `UIButton.buttonWithType(...)`  is a class method (or better: was as class method in Swift 1).

Comment: I get that part, but don't just confused as in how something that mutates ie and is an instance is derived from a class method

Answer (score 2):

If you cmd click the buttonWithType you will see that in swift its declared as

```
class func buttonWithType(buttonType: UIButtonType) -> AnyObject!
```

Since the type it returns is AnyObject! you need to type cast it back to UIButton.

Comment: its actually an optional and it can be nil

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking ahead, will edit my post, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.1 is now

```
var button = UIButton(type: .System)
```

so no need to downcast with .buttonWithType