# Tesseract initialization error

Tags: tesseract

Using this github page, https://github.com/robmathews/OCR-iOS-Example, I downloaded and installed the repo and followed the instructions. Trying to launch the .xcodeproj file on my phone gives an exception in Tesseract.mm:

```
- (id)initWithDataPath:(NSString *)dataPath language:(NSString *)language {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dataPath = dataPath;
        _language = language;
        _variables = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [self copyDataToDocumentsDirectory];
        _tesseract = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

        BOOL success = [self initEngine];
        if (!success) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

On the `return NO` line, xcode says `Cannot initialize return object of type 'Tesseract *' with an rvalue of type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool')`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NO` is a bool value. The return type is (as you defined) `id` (should be [instancetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id) )

You've to return `nil` there.

Comment: pls add details and I might help you