# When to use id in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I've just been reading and learning about `instancetype` and how in most cases it should be used instead of `id` in modern objective-c. Can I just ask when, then, would it be advisable to actually use `id` and not `instancetype`?
Thanks.

Comment: And good one about this, which is even more appropriate than link above : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652187/3402095

Comment: Yes, I've just been reading that Whirlwind, but I need the id use cases to round off what I've learned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**id**

`id` is the generic type variable. Id doesn't warn us at compile time but it will crash if there is any problem.

**Instancetype**

`instancetype`   does type checking for us at compile time to warn us of problems.

eg:

**Animal.h**

```
@interface Animal : NSObject

+ (id)giveMeAnimalA;
+ (instancetype)giveMeAnimalB;
+ (Animal *)giveMeAnimalC;

@end
```

**Animal.m**

```
@implementation Animal

+ (id)giveMeAnimalA {
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];
}

+ (instancetype)giveMeAnimalB {
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];
}

+ (Animal *)giveMeAnimalC {
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Suppose if we use `[[Animal giveMeAnimalA] count];`

The compiler will warn us of nothing, but we will crash at runtime with an exception because   Animal   doesn't have a   count   method.

And If we use `[[Animal giveMeAnimalB] count];`

The compiler would immediately warn us that   Animal   does not have a   count   method, and we could avoid crashing at runtime. But wouldn't it be simpler just to make our return type   Animal*  ?

Imagine we have a `Dog` subclass of `Animal`:

```
@interface Dog : Animal

- (void)makeSound;

@end
```

Now if we tried to call

```
[[Dog giveMeAnimalC] makeSound];
```

This wouldn't work because we would have been returned an  `Animal` that doesn't have a `makeSound` method.

Answer (score 3):

For complete last answer, i suggest you an example when Id is supported. It's on the ForIn Loop (fast enumeration)

Imagine, you have an array with three different objects like below :

```
    NSArray *anotherArray = @[@"One element of Another Array",@"Second Element of Another Array"];
    NSArray *array = @[@"First",@[anotherArray],@(12)];

    for (id item in array)
    {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Im a NSString");
        }

        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Im a NSArray");
        }

        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Im a NSNumber");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The id is a generic data type which can hold any type of data like nsstring,uiimage,nsarray and remaining all,so if you are having the requirements like returning the objects dynamically from a method you better use the return type of that method as id,hope you will get it

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `instancetype` as return type when the type of the value that is returned is not known beforehand. If a method might return either an `NSButton` or an `NSString` depending on context, you can only use `id`.

`instancetype` is just a placeholder for the class that it is being used in; if a method of `class Foo` is like

```
- (instancetype) getMeFoo
```

then it is equivalent to

```
- (Foo *) getMeFoo
```

It can not return an `NSString`; the compiler would complain. However,

```
- (id) getMeFoo
```

can return any class type.

You could theoretically use a common superclass of the possibly returned types (for example, `NSObject`); but then you would need to typecast it when assigning to a concrete variable, or the compiler would bug you with warnings.

```
- (NSObject *) getMeFoo {
    return @"foo!";
}
NSString *myString = (NSString *)[self getMeFoo];
```

The `id` type is "automatically" cast:

```
- (id) getMeFoo {
    return @"foo!";
}
NSString *myString = [self getMeFoo];
```

But never forget to check if you really got the expected type:

```
NSString *myString = [self getMeFoo];
if (![myString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // Danger, Will Robinson!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"I've just been reading and learning about instancetype and how in most cases it should be used instead of id in modern objective-c. Can I just ask when, then, would it be advisable to actually use id and not instancetype? Thanks."

You learned wrong. Kind of. The problem is that a language like Objective-C is complicated, and every rule will come with a long list of "do this IF a and b and c"... which you have to understand.

instancetype is used in one very particular situation: As the return type of init methods. You can't use for example UIButton* because an init method of UIButton could be used by a subclass, so the init method doesn't actually a UIButton but some subclass. That's why "id" was used which means "some object but I have no idea which object actually". "instancetype" on the other hand tells the compiler "you are clever, you figure it out. So with [[UIButton alloc] init] the compiler knows it returns UIButton*. [[MyButtonSubclass alloc] init] the compiler knows it returns MyButtonSubclass*.

In no other situation would you use instancetype.

Always give the compiler as much information as you can. If you have an object declared as UIButton* the compiler knows it's a UIButton or a subclass. If you have an object declared as id the compiler knows nothing. That means the compiler can't tell you if you do something stupid (like assigning a UIButton* to an NSString*, or calling the length method on a UIButton).