# Pros and cons of using "id" as the return type of a custom "init" method, instead of a pointer to that class?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

Assume the following Objective-C class:

```
@interface Appliance : NSObject
{
    NSString *productName;
    int voltage;
}
@end
```

What are the pros and cons of implementing init method A instead of B?

```
A) -(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
B) -(Appliance *)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
```

I see they both work in XCode, i.e. they both will result in a valid Appliance instance.  "A" seems to be the standard among books I've read and codebases I've looked at, and I'm wondering why this is.

Comment: Particularly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652187/1214800) excellent answer.

Comment: Consider the case of a subclass overriding the `initWithName:` method and then you'll understand why option "B" is not a good idea.

Comment: The answer of the linked Q by catfish_man is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, reopen. :-)

Indeed, you did not ask for the difference `id` vs. `instancetype`. And for `-init…` the answer to this non-asked Q would be easy: There is no difference, because the compiler converts `id` to `instancetype` silently.

You asked for `id` vs. `CustomClass*`. And you get a completely different answer from me: With `CustomClass*` a subclass had to cast the result of the superclass' designated initializer. Let's have an example:

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
- (BaseClass*)initWithWhatever; // Typed to class, designated initializer
@end

@implementation BaseClass
- (BaseClass*)initWithWhatever // Typed to class
{
  self = [super init]; // What's the return type of -init (NSObject)?
  …
}
@end

@interface Subclass : BaseClass
// First problem: I like it to announce in the interface, that a class overwrites
// a method of the base class. Doing so I would have to change the return type. Ugly.
// If I do not redeclare -initWithWhatever it is inherited from BaseClass, still
// having BaseClass* as the return type. Is that the truth? Really?

// However, I do not overwrite it here, but have a new initializer.
- (Subclass*)initWithSomethingElse;
@end

@implementation Subclass
- (Subclass*)initWithSomethingElse
{
  // Second Problem:
  // First, I have to execute the superclass' designated initializer
  self = [super initWithWhatever];
  // Wait a minute! 
  // self is a reference to Subclass. The return value of -initWithWhatever has the type 
  // BaseClass*. So I assign a reference of the base class to a reference of the subclass: 
  // Compiler error, false positive. The code is correct.
  // So I would have to cast. Ugly, ugly, ugly.
@end
…
// Third problem:
Subclass *object = [[Subclass alloc] initWithWhatever];
// Typing -initWithWhatever to BaseClass* would lead to a compiler error here again. 
// Compiler error, false positive. The code is correct.
```

To make the long story short: Without a mass of castings it would be impossible to type initializers to the concrete class.

Answer (score 3):

Point in fact, for quite some time the best practice return type from a class initializer (in Objective-C) is `instancetype` instead of `id`.

Comment: True - best provide some corroborating evidence though.

Comment: Interesting though it may be, this answer doesn't directly address my question, which is why (id) is now the apparent default implementation.  That is, unless (instancetype) and (Appliance *) are synonymous in this case.

Also, many people who post questions here are in the habit of doing so only after we've exhausted other resources (Google et al), so "leaving the homework to the student" doesn't leave us with many alternatives.

Comment: @toomanyrichies But `id` is not the modern default. `instancetype` is the modern return type for `init` methods.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the post.  I read it as "For quite some time, the best practice... was (instancetype) instead of id.", not "...is (instancetype)...".  My apologies.

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, quite a few Cocoa initializers use `(id)`.  This is the basis for my claim that `(id)` appears to be the default.  Source and examples here- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: For `-init…` it is quite meaningless to use `instancetype`,  because clang uses that type, if `id` is used. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features So it is only a matter of being explicit.

Comment: @toomanyrichies No, `instancetype` and `Application*` are not synonymous in every case.  For the sender of an message, `instancetype` and the class of the receiver, which can be a subclass(!), are synonymous, only for the implementor it is synonymous to the type of self. I'd like to explain that longer, but the Q is closed.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I understand your meaning.  Thanks.