# In swift, how do I return an object of the same type that conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, return-value, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol

```
protocol JSONInitializable {
    static func initialize(fromJSON: NSDictionary) throws -> Self?
}
```

Now I'm trying to make that function return whatever class has conformed to the protocol. I.e. if I have class `Foo` conforming to the protocol, I want to return a `Foo` object from the method. How can I do this?

```
extension Foo: JSONInitializable {
    static func initialize(fromJSON: NSDictionary) throws -> Foo? {
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Method 'initialize' in non-final class 'Foo' must return 'Self' to conform to protocol 'JSONInitializable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocomplete will help you, but basically, if `Foo` is a class, you just need a method which matches the exact signature of the method in your protocol:

```
class Foo {}

protocol JSONInitializable {
    static func initialize(fromJSON: [String : AnyObject]) throws -> Self?
}

extension Foo: JSONInitializable {
    static func initialize(fromJSON: [String : AnyObject]) throws -> Self? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

As a note here, you will have to, within this method, replace *all* instances of `Foo` with `Self`.  If you want to use a constructor, it will have to be one marked as required.

With this in mind, it probably makes more sense to change your protocol to requiring an initializer rather than a static method called `initialize`, in which case, take a look at [Blake Lockley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36272466/2792531).  However, this answer stands to answer the question of how to deal with `Self` in protocols, as there are certainly cases where we might want a method that returns `Self` that isn't an initializer.

---

If `Foo` is not a class, it is a value type which cannot be subclasses, and as such, we return the name of the type:

```
struct Foo: JSONInitializable {
    static func initialize(fromJSON: [String : AnyObject]) throws -> Foo? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

```
enum Foo: JSONInitializable {
    case One, Two, Three

    static func initialize(fromJSON: [String : AnyObject]) throws -> Foo? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

The reason you need to return `Self?` from the method in the case of a class is because of inheritance.  The protocol declares that if you conform to it, you will have a method called `initialize` whose return type will be an optional version of whatever you are.

If we write `Foo`'s `initialize` method as you wrote it, then if we subclass `Foo` with `Bar`, then now we have broken our conformance to the protocol.  `Bar` has inherited the conformance to the protocol from `Foo`, but it doesn't have a method which is called `initialize` and returns `Bar?`.  It has one that returns `Foo`.

Using `Self` here means that when our subclasses inherit this method, it will return whatever type they are.  `Self` is Swift's equivalent of [Objective-C's `instancetype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8972221/2792531).

Comment: So this would let me return object of type `Foo` from the method?

Comment: It returns `Foo` if you call it on an instance of `Foo`.  If you subclass `Foo` to make `class Bar: Foo`, it will return `Bar`.

Comment: I just tried this and now it gives me an error when I try to return an object of type `Foo` from the method. It says `Cannot convert expression of type 'Foo' to return type 'Self?'` I am using xcode 7.3 if that helps anything

Comment: You will have to replace all references of `Foo` with `Self` in this method.  If you want to use a constructor, it will have to be one marked as `required`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm kinda lost how to do that. I want to do `let f = Foo(); return f`. That gives the error. Then I try `return f.self()` another error. So I'm not sure what to return now

Comment: `let f = self.init()`, but `Foo` will have to have the zero-argument `init` method marked as `required` for this to work.

Comment: Aha, I see why a required constructor is needed. Thanks

Comment: And required initializers must be declared in the class itself (not in extensions).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in nhgrif answer change the return type of `Foo?` to `self?`.

**Alternatively**

In Swift you can declare `init`s in protocol so try something like this:

```
protocol JSONInitializable {
    init?(fromJSON: NSDictionary) throws
}

extension Foo: JSONInitializable {
    required init?(fromJSON: NSDictionary) throws {
      //Possibly throws or returns nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `convenience` and `required` in that extension

Comment: You need `required`.  You do not necessarily need `convenience`.  It's also worth mentioning that Objective-C protocols can & have declared initializers are part of the protocol.  For further reading, [see the `NSCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/).

Comment: I just tried this way, and the error is saying that I can only do this in the definition of a non-final class, i.e. extensions don't work

Comment: For further reading on the `required` keyword and why it's needed here, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531).

Comment: @Smac89 have you declared your `Foo` class already before the extension? if not you can include the protocol in your implementation without using an extension like so: `Foo: JSONInitializable { required init?...}`

Comment: Yea the class is already declared, I can't change it though which is why I was looking into creating this extra constructor